# Is there any difference between 'Had we would have' and 'If we would have'?

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals

1. Had we would have taken the original square root instead of Principal Square root, our extraneous solution might/would have worked"
2. If we would have taken the original square root instead of Principal Square root, our extraneous solution might/would have worked.

Is there any difference between those two sentences?

If any, when should we use one over the other?

[UPDATE]
I'm not a native English speaker and I used google translator and both of the sentences showed the same result.

I tried to use [Ginger](https://www.gingersoftware.com/grammarcheck) to check if there is any grammatical mistake, there wasn't any.

Comment: "Had we would have" just sounds weird.

Comment: Ikr, but I can't really recall where I heard it the last time, but I'm sure I did. Thus the confusion!

Comment: "Had we would have taken" is ungrammatical.  What about "Had we taken... ...our results would have been..."

Comment: The difference is that the second one is common in American English, but considered ungrammatical by many educated people, and the first one is considered ungrammatical by nearly everyone.

Comment: A conditional clause can be introduced either by "Had" or "If".

Comment: I tried to Ginger it https://www.gingersoftware.com/grammarcheck and it didn't show any grammatical error @PeterShor

Comment: @Daksh Gargas: That just shows that Ginger is not a very good grammar checker.

Comment: Yeah, you're right @PeterShor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are ungrammatical, so the difference is moot.

The right form is, "Had we taken the original square root...."

or

"If we had taken the original square root...."

"*Done* the square root" is weak.

It's not a rule these days, but an *if* (or *had*) clause should be followed by a *then* clause.

*If we had taken the original square root...then our extraneous solution might/would have worked.*

Formal logic and math use *if...then* for conditional statements, and I think the pairing works well in ordinary writing, too.  Again, not a rule but a good habit.